# getting at these ajax values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax request that returns the following.

```
{
"field1":{"label1":"message1"},
"field2":{"lable1":"message1"}
}
```

How can I reaad the values of "field1" and message1? The problem is that I don't know the names of these labels, so right now they're label1, label2, but it varies.

I'm trying this, but it gives me an object.

```
for (oneline in response) {
   alert(response[oneline]);
}
```

Comment: jQuery uses JSON.parse().  JSON.stringify({"foo":{"bar":["value","value"]}}) is the opposite, and spits out a string.  excellent for alerting if you don't have firebug or Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you already parsed the JSON, as you say you get an object. You can access it then like a normal JavaScript object:

```
for (var data in response) {
   for(var message in response[data]) {
       alert(response[date][message]);
   } 
}
```

*Edit: Updated as the fields of the objects are unknown too.*

`oneline` will have the values `field1` and `field2`.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the names of these labels, so right now they're label1, label2, but it varies.

Comment: @silow: Then you have to loop over them too. I update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var oneline in response) {
   alert(response[oneline].label1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`alert(response.field1.label1)`

Answer (score 1):

```
for (oneline in response) {
 alert(JSON.stringify(oneline));
}
```

JSON.parse(), the opposite of what you want, is used by jQuery() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

JSON.stringify({whatever:values});  will spit out a string of any valid JSON.

Comment: @silow pull the JS you need from this site, if the code does not fire right away. 
https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js